# How to check the given random number is not in descending order?

Tags: javascript

I have generated a **4 digit random number**, Where the random number should not be in `descending order`. It should not be like **7654 **.

Code:

```
function descendingOrder(n) {
   let num = n.toString();
      for (var i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
        if (num.substr(i) > num.substr(++i)) {
             alert('This pattern can't be used');
         }
         else {
             return parseInt(n);
         }
       }
}
descendingOrder(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000));
```

This code just compares first and second digits and gives an **alert message
**. Could someone please help?

Thanks

I've tried to generate a random number, which should not be in a descending order. But, it didn't work.

Comment: Does `7000` count as descending, or is it only adjacent numbers like `7654` and `4321`?

Comment: If it's adjacent, you can test for each: `9876, 8765, 7654, 6543, 5432, 4321`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to use only 4 digits, better to limit max number to 9999.
2. You can break iteration at the first case, when next digit bigger then previous.

```js
    function descendingOrder(n) {
        let num = n.toString();
        var i = 0;
        while (i<=num.length) {
            if (num.substr(i) < num.substr(i+1)) {
                alert('This pattern can be used');
                return parseInt(n);
            } 
            i++;
        }
        alert('This pattern cannot be used');
    }
    descendingOrder(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 8999));
```

Comment: oh, answer already given earlier )

Comment: thank you for your answer. Why do we use i++ after the if statement?

Comment: because I've changed defined repeats (for) to undefined (while)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly iterate over every pair of adjacent digits. If any digit is less than the succeeding digit, then it is not in descending order.

```js
function descendingOrder(n) {
   let num = n.toString();
   for (let i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i++) {
    if (num[i] < num[i + 1]) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
let n = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
console.log(n);
if (descendingOrder(n)) console.log("This pattern can't be used");
```